# MongoDB : How to add an `id` field to a collection?

Tags: mongodb

I want to add an `id` field to a collection,the number starts from `1`.
For example,
there is a collection articles：

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("98r498jfgragaja9ra4"),"titile":"foo","content":"foo..."}
{"_id" : ObjectId("498aut89auhgua4940q"),"titile":"bar","content":"bar..."}
{"_id" : ObjectId("30ua9ah984yhtauiga9"),"titile":"hello","content":"hello..."}
```

after adding `id` field, the result looks like this:

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("98r498jfgragaja9ra4"),"titile":"foo","content":"foo...","id":"1"}
{"_id" : ObjectId("498aut89auhgua4940q"),"titile":"bar","content":"bar...","id":"2"}
{"_id" : ObjectId("30ua9ah984yhtauiga9"),"titile":"hello","content":"hello...","id":"3"}
```

How to do it?

Comment: You need to show us what you've tried so far, even if it's not working...

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB's documentation offers a couple of suggestions about how to do this:

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/

Comment: Please include the suggestion in your answer, link only answers are not cool